# PHP: Skipping code when file isn't upload to email via contact form

Tags: php, email, contact-form

I'm trying to get the form to skip the code for file vailidates and checks
I was told to use: `iF($_FILES["fileToUpload"] == UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE) {`

I have tryed to implement this in to my code but I am new to php, I think I may have messed up the headers. Now when I send the email without the attachment or not it skips all the file checks.

I have commented lines were I have tried skiping the code.

If I haven't given enough details for info please let me know.

```
<?php
// Turn off all error reporting
error_reporting(0);

// Report simple running errors
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

// Reporting E_NOTICE can be good too (to report uninitialized
// variables or catch variable name misspellings ...)
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);

// Report all errors except E_NOTICE
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

// Report all PHP errors (see changelog)
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Report all PHP errors
error_reporting(-1);

// Same as error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);


$to = 'test@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'Website Submission';
    $company_name = $_POST['company_name'];
    $ref = $_POST['ref'];
    $website = $_POST['website'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $tel = $_POST['tel'];
    $fromweb = $_POST['fromweb'];
    $qr = $_POST['qr'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

       $body = <<<EMAIL

    <html>

    <p><h3>Email from website.</h3></p>

    <p><strong>Company Name:</strong> $company_name</p>
    <p><strong>Ref:</strong> $ref</p>
    <p><strong>Website:</strong> $website</p>
    <p><strong>Email:</strong> $email</p>
    <p><strong>Tel:</strong> $tel</p>
    <p><strong>Create From Website:</strong> $fromweb</p>
    <p><strong>Add QR Code:</strong> $qr</p>
    <p><strong>File Location:</strong> $target_file</p>
    <p><strong>Message:</strong> $message</p>


    </html>

EMAIL;
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////// \/
    // SKIPS IF NO FILE

    iF($_FILES["fileToUpload"] == UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE)  {
    // no file selected, do skip



    $target_dir = "uploads/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image

    // Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        echo '<p style="color:red;">Sorry, file already exists.</p>';
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check file size
    if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 150000000) { // Byte = 150MB
        echo '<p style="color:red;">Sorry, your file is larger than 150MB.</p>';
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Allow certain file formats
    if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
    && $imageFileType != "gif" && $imageFileType != "eps" && $imageFileType != "tiff" 
    && $imageFileType != "psd") {
        echo '<p style="color:red;">Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG, GIF, TIF, EPS and PSD files are allowed.</p>';
    if($imageFileType !=null) {
        echo "no file uploaded";

        }
        $uploadOk = 0;




    }
    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        die('<p style="color:red;">Sorry, your file was not uploaded.</p>');
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        } else {
            echo '<p style="color:red;">Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.</p>';

        }
    }



/* Attachment File 
Attachment location */
$file_name = $target_file;

$path = $file_name;

// Read the file content

$file = $file_name;
$file_size = filesize($file_name);
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
$content = fread($handle, $file_size);
fclose($handle);
$content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));




/* Set the email header 
Generate a boundary */
$boundary = md5(uniqid(time()));

// Email header
// $header = "From: ".$from_name." \r\n";

 } //skiping file upload

///////////////////////////////////////////////////// /\


$header = 'From: <noreply@email.co.uk>' . "\r\n";
// $header .= "Reply-To: ".$reply_to."\r\n";
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";



// Multipart wraps the Email Content and Attachment

///////////////////////////////////////////////////// \/
// SKIPS IF NO FILE
iF($_FILES["fileToUpload"] == UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE)  {


$header .= " boundary=\"".$boundary."\"";
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////// /\

//$message .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n\r\n";


/* Email content
Content-type can be text/plain or text/html */
// $message .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n";

// this header below is the important one if you want HTML message

$header .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n";

$message .= "\r\n";
$message .= "$body\r\n";


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////// \/
// SKIPS IF NO FILE
iF($_FILES["fileToUpload"] == UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE)  {

$message .= " name=\"".$file_name."\"\r\n";
$message .= " filename=\"".$file_name."\"\r\n";
$message .= "\r\n".$content."\r\n";

/* Attachment
Edit content type for different file extensions */
$message .= "Content-Type: application/xml;\r\n";
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$message .= "Content-Disposition: attachment;\r\n";
$message .= "--".$boundary."--\r\n";
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////// /\

if ($_POST['submit']){
mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);
echo '<p style="color:green;">Message Successfully Sent.</p>';
} else {

    die('<p>Error Email Not Sent</p>');
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already added condition where needed.

Just replace the condition with

```
if(isset($_FILES["fileToUpload"]) && !empty($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_path"])){
 // your code here
}
```

Comment: What condition do I need to replace this with and to I put all my code inbetween ?

Comment: yes put all your attachment/file related code inbetween this condition.
Currently you are using this condition iF($_FILES["fileToUpload"] == UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE) ..you can replace this with the suggested condition

Comment: I have update my code but im getting the error that the file already exists (Sorry, file already exists.)(Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG, GIF, TIF, EPS and PSD files are allowed.)(Sorry, your file was not uploaded.). when upload nothing, and when i do upload a file I only get a attachment that has no name and is a document with the code in it. http://www.codeshare.io/ikR8O

Comment: what is the file type field name in your html form?

Comment: type="file" and name="fileToUpload"

Comment: i have updated the answer. Actually when form is submitted without uploading any file then $_FILES contains all the keys with empty value due to which old condition passes.
update the condition and check

Comment: I have altered the code and it is now sending a file named: noname. if i upload a file or not this is what the email looks like: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9833562/emailtest.png. and this is my current code any idea what it could  be? http://www.codeshare.io/ikR8O

Comment: well this works in most of the cases, if its not working for you then you can check whether any file exists or not at $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_path'] ( try the solution mentioned by Mert Dogan)

Answer (score 0):

You can use is_uploaded_file():

```
if(!file_exists($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name']) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'])) {
    echo 'No upload';
}
```